# как объявить структуру в файле глобальных констант с внутренним связыванием?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, структуры

.h file

```
static struct offsets {

        std::array<DWORD, offsetSize> minerals = { 0x168, 0x1B8, 0x30, 0x10 };
        std::array<DWORD, offsetSize> foods = { 0x168, 0x1B8, 0x30, 0x18 };
        std::array<DWORD, offsetSize> influence = { 0x168, 0x1B8, 0x30, 0x38 };
        std::array<DWORD, offsetSize> unity = { 0x168, 0x1B8, 0x30, 0x40 };
        std::array<DWORD, offsetSize> alloys = { 0x168, 0x1B8, 0x30, 0x4C };
        std::array<DWORD, offsetSize> consumer_goods = { 0x168, 0x1B8, 0x30, 0x54 };

    }
```

далее в этом же файле я объявляю:

`const offsets offsetList`

и хочу использовать исключительно `offsetlist` для доступа к значениям структуры, а саму структуру нужно скрыть, чтоб она не была доступна в других файлах, т.е чтоб пользователи не могли объявить свою структуру, а обращались исключительно к глобальной константе `offsetList`. Не смотря на то что я объявил структуру как `static`, она доступна в других файлах при подключении заголовка.

У меня есть вариант решения, но он не работает как нужно:
А именно, поместить объявление структуры в `constants.cpp` вместо `constants.h`, но объявить я могу ее исключительно в `constants.cpp` тем самым теперь не видно стуктуру, а так же `const offsets offsetList`. А если объявить структуру в `constants.h` файле, а затем определить ее в `constants.cpp` то всё равно эта структура будет видна во всех файлах где подключен `constants.h`

Еще пробовал решить это с помощью анонимного namespace, но мой компилятор всё равно видит этот объект:

[image: да]

Как объявить структуру с внутренним связыванием, а затем определить ее глобально в `constants.h` чтобы пользователи не смогли определять свои объекты этой структуры?

Comment: Почитайте о том, что такое синглтон. Это позволит вам иметь единственный объект структуры, хотя и не с помощью того механизма, который вы хотите.

Comment: Приведенный код неполный и неработоспособный. Чтобы пользователи не смогли определять свои объекты этой структуры все конструкторы и операторы копирования у нее должны быть приватными / удалены.

Answer (score 1):

Краткий намек на синглтон:

```
struct offsets
{
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;  // не стал таскать ваше многословное определение
    friend offsets& offsetList();
private:
    offsets() = default;
    offsets(const offsets&) = delete;
};

offsets& offsetList()  // Вынес из определения класса для краткости обращения
{                      // чтоб не таскать имя offsets::offsetList()
    static offsets o;
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    cout << offsetList().a << offsetList().b;
    // offsets s;                   <- это работать не будет
    // offsets t(offsetList());     <- это работать не будет
}
```